How to calculate yield -> price conversion for when issue treasury note instruments?
Thanks for peeking. I've tried scouring all of the web for an answer but keep coming up short. Which python package can help convert bond yield to price conversion using the below information? Bloomberg/Tradeweb is showing a converted price to 101.7517925, but every python package shows something slightly different because it's not incorporating the adjusted "interested accrues" date for this re-opening treasury note.
Vendors offer this package for 10k per month as it's a specialized financial software that takes into account all nuances of treasury bond pricing, but I can't afford that! Any sources would be helpful!
Cusip: 912810UB2
rade Date: 07/15/2024
Settle Date: 07/31/2024
YTM (BBG Street Convention): 4.49
Issue Date: 07/31/2024
Interest Accrued: 05/15/2024
1st Coupon Date: 11/15/2024
Maturity Date: 05/15/2044
Semi Annual Coupon 4.625

Rateslib and Quantlib both do this.
from rateslib import *  # Python 3.12, Rateslib 1.4.0

bond = FixedRateBond(
    effective=dt(2024, 5, 15),
    termination=dt(2044, 5, 15),
    spec="us_gb",  # <- Street convention for US Treasuries.
    fixed_rate=4.625
)
bond.price(ytm=4.49, settlement=dt(2024, 7, 31))
# 101.75179247635955

bond = FixedRateBond(
    effective=dt(2024, 5, 15),
    termination=dt(2044, 5, 15),
    spec="us_gb_tsy",  # <- Treasury convention for US Treasuries.
    fixed_rate=4.625
)
bond.price(ytm=4.49, settlement=dt(2024, 7, 31))
# 101.74563944560269


This is amazing! Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!!

What would be the equivalent library from Quantlib that could reproduce this?

I don't know. Here a searched link to get you started: https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/44319/29443
